# KDB: how to search a table with a list

Tags: kdb

I have the following table t:

```
t:([]sym:3#`ibm;time:10:01:01 10:01:04 10:01:08;price:100 101 105;val:("hello";"world";"test"))
```

How do I perform the following query:

```
select from t where val in ("hello"; "test")
```

Wherein I am expecting the following result:

```
sym time        price val
---------------------------
ibm 10:01:01    100   hello
ibm 10:01:08    105   test
```

Comment: Your query works fine and results in your desired answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 q) select from t where any val like/: ("hello"; "test")
```

Output:

```
sym time        price val
---------------------------
ibm 10:01:01    100   hello
ibm 10:01:08    105   test
```

Answer (score 8):

It looks like your query does return the result you require.

Alternatively, the keyword 'like' can be used.

When we use a where clause at the end of a select statement, the 'where' section expects a single boolean value to tell it whether the column should be selected.

When we do `where val in "hello"` , it will actually return a boolean for *each element of the string* that it matches on (when it isn't wrapped):

```
q)val:"hello"
q)val in "hello"
11111b
```

Therefore, to obtain a single boolean returned we use the keyword `like`

```
q)val like "hello"
1b
```

Furthermore, when passing a *list of strings* to a where clause, an 'each-right' adverb should be used to instruct the where clause to operate on each instance of the list.

```
q)val like/: ("hello";"test")
10b
```

However, we are again faced with multiple booleans, when the where clause expects a single

Therefore we use the keyword `any` to return results when *either* *hello* or *test* are present.

```
q)any val like/: ("hello";"test")
1b
```

And we can see, this gives the results required

```
q)select from t where any val like/: ("hello";"test")
sym time     price val
--------------------------
ibm 10:01:01 100   "hello"
ibm 10:01:08 105   "test"
```

Hope this helps